# Smooth Page Indicator

Tags: flutter

Even though I added the Smooth Page Indicator, it doesn't show up in the emulator. I am also getting a few debug errors.
e.g. 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: '!_debugDoingThisLayout': is not true.

RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#1ac32 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#9012c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

and, I can't switch between pages. How can I solve the problem?

```
import 'package:deneme/modul2.dart';
import 'package:deneme/modul3.dart';
import 'package:deneme/modul4.dart';
import 'package:deneme/modul5.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smooth_page_indicator/smooth_page_indicator.dart';

class Modul1 extends StatelessWidget {
  final _controller = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Image.asset("images/modül1.png"),
            SizedBox(
            height: 100,
            child: PageView(
            controller: _controller,
            children: [
              Modul1(),
              const Modul2(),
              const Modul3(),
              const Modul4(),
              const Modul5(),
               ],
              ),
            ),
            SmoothPageIndicator(
              controller: _controller,
                count: 5,
              axisDirection: Axis.vertical,
              effect: SlideEffect(
                  activeDotColor: Colors.white54,
                  dotHeight: 10,
                  dotColor: Colors.white,
                  dotWidth: 10,
                ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't had this error when I test it, but I made some changes:

1. I've changed the dots color because it was white on a white background which makes them invisible.
2. add `Expanded` instead of `SizedBox` for testing purposes.
3. made `axisDirection` horizontal in `SmoothPageIndicator`.
4. Replaced the `Models` with `Text` because missing classes.

And this was the result(Idk why it got stretched):
[image: result]

Try this example on separate file and test it and tell me what the result you had.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smooth_page_indicator/smooth_page_indicator.dart';

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final _controller = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Image.asset("images/modül1.png"),
            Expanded(
              child: PageView(
                controller: _controller,
                children: const [
                  Center(
                    child: Text('Page 1'),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Text('Page 2'),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Text('Page 3'),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Text('Page 4'),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Text('Page 5'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SmoothPageIndicator(
              controller: _controller,
              count: 5,
              axisDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              effect: const SlideEffect(
                activeDotColor: Colors.white54,
                dotHeight: 10,
                dotColor: Colors.blue,
                dotWidth: 10,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 50),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The text I put them for example. I don't  have your class. for the error remove const keyword before the opening bracket

Comment: @sinemkaraoglu Can you explain the links you've wrote? What is the picture? do you mean the expected output or the actual output?

Comment: You have to `fit: BoxFit.fitWidth` . or define it dimensions manually using `SizedBox` widget. And I think if your main issue solved accept the answer. happy to help more over.